# Keyboard shortcut for show window.(opposite function of Command-H)

Tags: keyboard

If I press Command-H, an activated window disappear. How can I make it appear with shortcuts?

Comment: Or more significantly, Command-Option-H, which hides all other windows. Using Cmd-Tab to restore them all one-by-one is pretty tedious but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be another answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no shortcut to bring the window back, because the app loses focus when hidden. To bring its windows back, you have to give it focus again.

The easiest way to do this is with the <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> shortcut. Press that, then leave <kbd>cmd</kbd> held down. You'll see the App Switcher:

[image]

From here, you can give focus to an app, as well as hide and show it without focusing.

**To focus an app and show it's windows:**
Open the app switcher, then (while still holding down <kbd>cmd</kbd> press <kbd>tab</kbd> until the darkened box is over the app you want to focus. Then, release the keys.

**To show an app's windows without focusing:**
Open the app switcher, then (while still holding down <kbd>cmd</kbd> press <kbd>tab</kbd> until the darkened box is over the app you want to focus. While still holding down <kbd>cmd</kbd>, press <kbd>h</kbd> Then, release the keys.

If you want to 'hide' one window and don't want the app to lose focus, you can minimize the window. Do that by clicking the green button at its top right, or using Window-> Mimize (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>).
To restore a minimized window, click its name in the app's Window menu. Or, you can either click the window's icon in the right of your dock, or the app's Dock icon (depending on your settings).

Comment: That's great answer. Is there any shortcut to restore minimized window?

Comment: @Sangdol Not as far as I know. It would be cool if there was one.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use the task switcher ( <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⇥ tab</kbd> ) to bring the application back into focus and display it normally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this `⇥` tab key?

Comment: Yes it is. I'll edit my answer.